How to merge or join two dataframes on the basis of partly matched columns
Have to dataframes which I need to merge
df_1
    Cities          Population  MLB
0   New York City   20153634    Yankees Mets
1   Los Angeles 13310447    Dodgers Angels
2   San Francisco   6657982         Giants Athletics

and df_2
        MLB  W  L
0   Red Sox 108.0   54.0
1   Yankees 100.0   62.0
2   Rays    90.0    72.0
3   Blue    73.0    89.0

How can I merge all this two dataframes on the basis of MLB column? If there are partly match of a string, like 'Yankees Mets' and 'Yankees', so choose the left one. Also, the W and L columns have to be concatenated too. Not merge nor join or other types of pandas merging tools helped me to gain the result.
Thank you all in advance

you can look into fuzzy matching, this question for example

Assuming these dataframes as input (slightly different from OP to include team "Other" and city "Boston"):
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Cities": ["New York City", "Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "Boston"],
        "Population": [20153634, 13310447, 6657982, 11111111],
        "MLB": ["Yankees Mets", "Dodgers Angels", "Giants Athletics", "Other Red Sox"],
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "MLB": ["Red Sox", "Yankees", "Rays", "Blue", "Other"],
        "W": [108.0, 100.0, 90.0, 73.0, 100.0],
        "L": [54.0, 62.0, 72.0, 89.0, 100.00],
    }
)

You can try this approach:
df1["MLB"] = df1["MLB"].apply(
    lambda x: [
        " ".join(combo)
        for r in range(1, len(x.split()) + 1)
        for combo in itertools.combinations(x.split(), r)
    ]
)
df1 = df1.explode("MLB")

out = (
    pd.merge(df1, df2, on="MLB", how="inner")
    .groupby("Cities")
    .agg({"Population": "first", "MLB": lambda x: " ".join(x), "W": "sum", "L": "sum"})
    .reset_index()
)

          Cities  Population            MLB      W      L
0         Boston    11111111  Other Red Sox  208.0  154.0
1  New York City    20153634        Yankees  100.0   62.0


Thank you for your support! I've tried your approach, but the result is an empty dataframe.
df1  gives me an exploded datframe, where each MLB string has its own row. But out result is an empty dataframe but with the right header

@denispchelkin it works with the data frames in my answer, which are similar to the ones in your question right now. If your data is different, you can edit your question to include new data frames containing  it.
